# Fetch certain records from db using SQL

Tags: sql, db2, self-join

I have a table with the multiple records where PLACE_ORDER entry is not there i.e order#594886579291. I want to fetch only order where PLACE_ORDER row is not there like 594886579291.

If I do a simple query like

```
SELECT * FROM ORDER_STATUS os WHERE os.SERVICE_NAME != 'OC'.
```

It returns orders 594886579290 & 594886579295 without OC. I need only 594886579291.

I tried self join but no luck.

FYI- I am using DB2.

[image: Table structure]

Comment: why -1 ? I did research and also put self joins, NOT exists but my data was getting repeated so I asked this question.

Comment: What is wanted is not clear & it is not obvious from your example. "fetch only order where PLACE_ORDER row is not there" is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to say what you mean. And give the rest of a [mcve]. Show parts you can do. Please use text, not images/links, for text, including tables & ERDs. Textual content in images/links cannot be searched for & cannot be cut & pasted. Also this is an easily found faq if you would google a clear concise statement of what you want without your particular strings/names. Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the order numbers:

```
SELECT order_number
FROM ORDER_STATUS os 
GROUP BY order_number
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN os.SERVICE_NAME = 'OC' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

If you want the full order details, then use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT os.*
FROM ORDER_STATUS os 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM ORDER_STATUS os2
                  WHERE os2.order_number = os.order_number AND
                        os2.SERVICE_NAME = 'OC'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
SELECT ORDER_NUMBER FROM ORDER_STATUS WHERE SERVICE_NAME != 'OC'
MINUS
SELECT ORDER_NUMBER FROM ORDER_STATUS WHERE SERVICE_NAME  = 'OC'
```

This can also be used as a sub select to a larger query:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM ORDER_STATUS
  WHERE ORDER_NUMBER IN (
     SELECT ORDER_NUMBER FROM ORDER_STATUS WHERE SERVICE_NAME != 'OC'
     MINUS
     SELECT ORDER_NUMBER FROM ORDER_STATUS WHERE SERVICE_NAME  = 'OC'
     )
```